# How do I use nexus proxy repository for springboot?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, nexus, nexus3

I have a springboot application with pom.xml as below specified. Normally, maven dependencies are downloaded by itself when specified but I want to fetch the dependencies from the proxy repository of nexus.

I had created a new proxy repository called maven-proxy-test and replaced xsi:schemaLocation url to "http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-proxy-test/" but that didn't add the dependencies to the repository

**Pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>udemy.springbatch</groupId>
    <artifactId>course</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>course</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I am quite new to devops and nexus. Any suggestion or help is appreciated.
Also, if it helps, I am using springboot 2.6.6 and nexus OSS 3

Answer (score -1):

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>public</id>
        <name>nexus</name>
        <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-proxy-test/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are against community guidelines. Please update answer to include some context and clarity